# Desired Result Data is not comming from compressed base64 string by scanning QR code from android phone?

Tags: java, android, base64

I have extracted base64 string from an image, then perform compression on the base64 string.Then generate QR code using this compressed string.
But when I scan(QR CODE) the result using android phone I am getting value like 17740296 which is not value I want. My purpose is that after getting the scanned value I will decompress it and display the image using bitmap from base64. What is the wrong in my code. I am using java code to generate QR CODE.(I have tried UTF-8 also but not working). This code is working for String but not for the image.

Compressing Code is -

```
public static String compressBD(String str) throws IOException {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return str;
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    return out.toString("ISO-8859-1");
}
```

Decompress Code is -

```
public static String decompressBD(String str) throws Exception {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return str.toString();
    }
    //     System.out.println("Input String length : " + str.toString().length());
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "ISO-8859-1"));
    String outStr = "";
    String line;
    while ((line=bf.readLine())!=null) {
        outStr += line;
    }
    //System.out.println("Output String lenght : " + outStr.length());
    return outStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this wont work.

Base64 ist an encoding that can be used entirely in strings. You can print it on a piece of paper, type it into your machine and decode an image fromt it.

However, if you use a gzip compression and transform this to a string, the compression generates bytes that are outside the string encoding and can not be printed or presented as string.

Base64 is meant to be the "compressed" encoding for strings. I would really encourage you not to use string as storage, but directly store the binary data, or transmitt it. This would also be considerably faster, since base64 encoding is very slow.

Its purpose is entirely to store binary content, that contains non printable bytes, in text messages. For what ever reason.

I hope it is understandable, but it basically means, you cant store a base64 zip content in a string. You have to store the binary representation if you want to compress.

Comment: He could turn that around, though. 1. compress binary data, then 2. encode in Base64 ...

Comment: yeah that can of course be done, but I assume most image formats or images are already compressed. A generic zip compression on image data does in most cases not work very well. He should perhaps try jpeg compression, or png if it should be lossles.

Comment: Yes, I agree on that part, too.

Comment: I am trying to implement this paper http://www.ijcat.com/archives/volume4/issue3/ijcatr04031002.pdf

Comment: I have quickly scanned the paper, from my point of view it suggest a RLE Encoding see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding. Your problem here is that you cant store the output of the zip compression in a string. You can try to improve the encoding yourself, or by implementing the algorithm in the paper, this one should work, since only printable characters are used